# How to accept the custom GET variable with Rewrite rule

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting

Within custom `post_type` i do using permanent links... And i'll making custom querys in the **ask** loop by `$_GET` variable.

### e.g.

- `www.(domain).com/ask?dates=today`
- `www.(domain).com/ask?rating=5`

Simple Query is:

```
<?php 
 $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'ask',
             ...,
             ...,
            'meta_key' => 'rating',
            'meta_value' => $_GET['rating']
       );
 $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

### 1

I how to rescue `www.(domain).com/ask/rating/5` in **404 error**! And pretend `www.(domain).com/ask/`

### 2

I am how to get this child variables in this link for custom query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To match two parameters try this, try this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteRule ^ask/([a-z]+)?/(.+)?$   ask/?$1=$2    [NC]
</IfModule>
```

It should rewrite `/ask/rating/5` to `/ask/?rating=5`

If you need to match more you can extend it to include four:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteRule ^ask/([a-z]+)?/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)?$ ask/?$1=$2    [NC] #matches two variables
    RewriteRule ^ask/([a-z]+)?/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)?/([a-z]+)?/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)?$   ask/?$1=$2&$2=$3    [NC] #matches four variables
</IfModule>
```

This can be extended as much as is needed

To put them into your query you are doing the right thing, using $_GET[''], maybe try

```
<?php
$args = array('post_type' => 'ask');
foreach (['rating', 'dates'] as $param){
    $args[$param] = $_GET[$param];
}
```

This will produce

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'ask',
    'rating' => 5,
    'dates' => 'today'
);
```

Which is the best I could do as you can't have two matching keys

Comment: Ty @Roshan Bhumbra, It support only two sector rule? Else this work like it `/ask/rating/5/dates/today` ? And, i am how to take variables from this link for my custom query?

Comment: @Onur Boz Don't forget to mark as the answer, by clicking the tick mark next to my answer, if it helped.